# In MongoDB aggregation pipeline, how to project a returned field into an array of that value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-java

In MongoDB 3.6, if I am using the java driver and aggregating, after matching, how can I project a particular field of the results into a single-element array of that type?  For example, one of my fields is a string, and I want to create a one-element string array so that I can perform a set union later between that value and a set (which is another value in the results).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [`Projections.computed`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/model/Projections.html#computed-java.lang.String-TExpression-) static method to output an array of single value.

Something like

```
Bson bson = computed("fname", Arrays.asList("$value"));
```

Verify:

```
BsonDocument bsonDocument = bson.toBsonDocument(BsonDocument.class, MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry());
System.out.print(bsonDocument.toString());// { "fname" : ["$value"] }
```

Comment: Thank you.  That worked and it is embarrassingly simple.  Maybe I should have tried something like that, but I usually assume that things are more complicated than they really are.  Either way, I wasn't seeing examples of this.